# NTFS permissions inheriting incorrectly as "this folder only"

Tags: file-permissions, access-control-list, ntfs, icacls

I have a full directory tree that was migrated from another server. I've created top level folders with the necessary permissions that I wish to propagate to all descendant files and folders. However, inheritance is only working for a single level.

All folders are owned by local Administrators group (set recursively)

All permissions were set explicitly using the Advanced permissions dialog as "this folder, subfolders, and files" and "replace children..." was checked.

Choosing any immediate subfolder and viewing permissions shows all inherited permissions as "this folder only" instead of "this folder, subfolders, and files" as expected. Any children below this folder do not show any inherited permissions at all.

I've already attempted to reset the child folders using icalcs. This processes all files and folders with no failures, yet the problem remains.

```
icacls "D:\parentDirectory\*" /q /c /t /reset
```

parentDirectory has permissions "this folder, subfolders, and files"

parentDirectory\child incorrectly has "this folder only" and cannot be changed as it is inherited

parentDirectory\child\grandchild has no permissions at all (except for System and Creator Owner)

Answer (score 1):

Open **Folder Properties** and click the *Advanced* button on the **Security** tab. In the **Advanced Security Settings** dialog, double-click the **Permission Entry** that you wish to correct. Make sure the *Only apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container* option is not selected.